# Why is this SSIS package throwing conversion errors?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

When I run it I get the following error:

> Error at Data Flow Task [SQL Server
>   Destination [164]]: The column
>   "SepticSystemType" can't be inserted
>   because the conversion between types
>   DT_NTEXT and DT_WSTR is not supported.

But according to this diagram that cast is legal:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141704.aspx

Am I missing something?

Comment: Just under that diagram, it also says that casting to DT_WSTR requires parameters.  Are you following that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a possible option. You could use `Data Conversion Transformation` task available in Data Flow Task to convert input from one data type to another. Following example shows how this can be done.

**Step-by-step process:**

1. Create two tables named `dbo.DataNText` and `dbo.DataUnicode` as shown in screenshots #**1** and #**2**.
2. Create a package with one data flow task. Configure data flow task with a OLE DB soruce, Data Conversion task and OLE DB destination. Refer screenshot #**6** to see how the tasks are configured. `NText` is a OLE DB source task; `Conversion` is a Data Conversion Transformation task; and `Unicode` is a OLE DB destination task.
3. NText is configured to retrieve data from table `dbo.DataNText`. Column mapping is done as shown in screenshot #**3**.
4. Conversion task is configured as shown in screenshot #**4**. Select the column to convert, provide a name to the output column. Usually it is named as `Copy of`. Change the data type to `Unicode String [DT_WSTR]` and provide a length `255`. These values are for this example to show how the conversion configuration is done.
5. Unicode is configured to save data to the table `dbo.DataUnicode`. Column mapping is done as shown in screenshot #**5**.
6. Sample package execution is shown in screenshot #**6**.
7. Sample data contents of both the tables are shown in screenshot #**7**.

This can also be achieved using `Derived Column Transformation` task.

Hope that helps.

**Screenshot #1:**

[image: 1]

**Screenshot #2:**

[image: 2]

**Screenshot #3:**

[image: 3]

**Screenshot #4:**

[image: 4]

**Screenshot #5:**

[image: 5]

**Screenshot #6:**

[image: 6]

**Screenshot #7:**

[image: 7]

Answer (score 1):

Just under that diagram, it also says that casting to DT_WSTR requires parameters. Are you following that?

(DT_WSTR,20) casts 20 byte pairs, or 20 Unicode characters, to the DT_WSTR data type.

edit: Please see Siva's answer for steps to achieve this with another task.

Comment: Hmm, it's an implicit conversion and it doesn't say in the error message.  Do you know where I could look to find this?

Comment: Also, I'm brand new to SSIS, please let me know if any of that didn't make sense ;)

Comment: @Abe You must be able to set it in your data flow task.  I can't help much more without being able to see the actual package, it's not my strong suit.

Comment: When I go into the task it will allow me to look at the input/output types, but it does not let me change them or specify how the conversion will take place.  I'll keep messing with it and keep you posted.  Thanks!